# (SCHEME) english words -> numbers

Tags: parsing, scheme, racket

I need help trying to get a program that takes english words and puts them into numbers. I have done everything up to thousands (thousand, million, billion..... vigintillion).

So I have to use lexer and parser. 
I'm pretty sure it has something to do with my parser function.

```
 #lang scheme
 (define calcp
(parser

(start start)
(end newline EOF)
(tokens value-tokens op-tokens)
(error (lambda (a b c) (void)))

(grammar

(start [() #f]
       ;; If there is an error, ignore everything before the error
       ;; and try to start over right after the error
       [(error start) $2]
       [(S) $1])

(S [(zero) $1]
   [(L) $1])
(zero [(ZERO) 0])
(L [(T) $1]
   [(T D) (expt 10 (thousands-number $1))]
   [(T D L) $1])
(T [(H) $1]
   [(A HUNDRED H) (+ (* $1 100) $3)]
   [(A HUNDRED) (* $1 100)])
(H [(B) $1]
   [(C) $1]
   [(C B) (+ $1 $2)]) 
(A [(UNDERTEN) (undertwenty-number $1)])
(B [(UNDERTWENTY) (undertwenty-number $1)]
   [(A) $1])
(C [(TENS) (tens-number $1)])
(D [(THOUSANDS) (thousands-number $1)])
)
```

)
  )

In this calculator for parser, L is part of a grammar that I define. 
In this case L-> T|TD|TDL. Where D is my thousands function.

This next code describes my list for all of the big number names.

```
 #lang scheme
 (define (thousands-number name)
   (cadr
    (assoc
     name
     '((thousand 3) (million 6) (billion 9) (trillion 12) (quadrillion 15) (quintillion 18) (sextillion 21) (septillion 24) (octillion 27) (nonillion 30) (decillion 33) (undecillion 36) (duodecillion 39)
               (tredecillion 42) (quattuordecillion 45) (quindecillion 48) (sexdecillion 51) (septendecillion 54) (octodecillion 57) (novemdecillion 60) (vigintillion 63)))))
```

What I am trying to do here is use the exponential function to be the numbers that have the many many zeroes, as I do not feel like hard coding the vast amounts of 10^33 or even 10^63 zeroes. 
I probably screwed up with the expt function itself inside parser, so I'm hoping someone can help mefigure that out.

The input: "two quintillion four hundred thirty-two quadrillion nine hundred two trillion eight billion one hundred seventy-six million six hundred forty thousand twelve" should be outputting: 2432902008176640012.

However my output is 176.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the updated code and **finished**:

```
(S [(zero) $1]
   [(L) $1])
(zero [(ZERO) 0])

**  (L [(T) $1]
   [(T D) (* (expt 10 $2) $1)]
   [(T D L) (+ (* (expt 10 $2) $1) $3) ]) **

(T [(H) $1]
   [(A HUNDRED H) (+ (* $1 100) $3)]
   [(A HUNDRED) (* $1 100)])
(H [(B) $1]
   [(C) $1]
   [(C B) (+ $1 $2)]) 
(A [(UNDERTEN) (undertwenty-number $1)])
(B [(UNDERTWENTY) (undertwenty-number $1)]
   [(A) $1])
(C [(TENS) (tens-number $1)])
(D [(THOUSANDS) (thousands-number $1)])
)
)
)
```